# Android csv file creation and editing

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have been working on this for a few weeks now a little bit at a time. This is an android app i am developing for multiple versions of Samsung tablets. I need to create a file and add text to it. I cannot do either. I have 2 different methods to add text using different text writers to add text to a file. Here is my code:

```
public void addTextToFile(String text) {
File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PODCASTS), "MyFile.csv");
if (!logFile.exists()) {
    try {
        logFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
try {
    BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
    buf.append(text);
    buf.newLine();
    buf.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public void write(String data){
OutputStream os;
OutputStreamWriter osw;
data += "\n";
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
    osw.write(data);
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: so what error are you getting? What is the behaviour?

Comment: Not getting any error messages, no file is being created and when I make one and ask it to edit the file it doesn't do anything. Cannot figure out what is wrong? Anyone have success in this area?

Comment: Show where and how you're calling the methods in your question.

Comment: Calling by saying:        String output = tNumber.getText ().toString () + seekBar.getProgress();    try { write (output); }catch (IOExeption e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

Answer (score 0):

Found my error, I did research at the beginning and thought i did not need permission to create a publicly view-able file, I gave myself permission in the android manifest like so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```